# How to load AJAX data after new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a website with different products. When a product is clicked, AJAX call gets the product data from the database. After this, I want to go to a new page, where product-data will be displayed. But there is the problem, when the new page is loaded, the data won't be displayed, because the data were loaded at the previous page.

Javascript:

```
$('#products').on('click', 'li', function(){
    document.location.href = "product.html";
    var datapk = $(this).attr('data-pk');
    console.log(datapk);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'connection.php',
        data: {
            'function': 'get_product_data',
            'datapk': datapk
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var productData = JSON.parse(data);
            displayProductData(productData);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
function get_product_data(){
    $datapk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datapk']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE prod_id = '$datapk'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbc'], $query) or die('Error querying database.');
    $json = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            $json[] = $row;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
    mysqli_close($db_name);
}
```

`Data-pk` is the unique ID in database.

Comment: If you're getting the product information via AJAX on the first page, why bother redirecting? If you do need to redirect, why bother with the AJAX?

Comment: I think you are not clear about your need.

Comment: aside from the fact there is literally no point in using AJAX for what you've described. mysql_* functions should really be replaced with msqli_* or PDO prepared statements in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory said..

Either it's `document.location.href = "product.html";` or `$.ajax({ ... })`

However, what's the difference between `document.location.href = "product.html` and `<a href='product.html'>`, you might ask yourself.